# Goldbach weak conjecture verification

Tags: analytic-number-theory

I found from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Goldbach%27s_weak_conjecture that Goldbach's weak conjecture might have been proven but the proof has not been peer reviewed yet. What results of the article still needs to be verified so that one can say that the result is a theorem?

Comment: Presumably, the paper has been sent to a journal, the journal has sent it to one or more referees, and the journal is waiting to hear from the referees. What the referees are currently trying to verify, only the referees know. But anyway if you have looked at the proof or any serious discussion of it you will appreciate that it involves a considerable amount of very deep mathematics. If someone told me exactly what still needs to be verified, I doubt I would understand it. Would you?

Comment: Well, maybe not.